# What method is called when I display a variable in a golang html template

Tags: html, templates, go, escaping

I am trying to figure out what method is called when I show a variable in an "html/template" template in Go via `{{ .SomeVariable }}`.

I am using the package "html/template".

I am using this function to render a template:

```
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, p *Page) {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("public/" + tmpl + ".html")
    t.Execute(w, p)
}
```

with

```
type Page struct {
    Title  string
    Users []*model.User
}
```

and an example template

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Listing Users</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Listing users</h1>

    {{range .Params}}
      <h3>
        id {{.Id }}
        &nbsp;
        email {{.Email}}
        &nbsp;
         name {{.Name}}
      </h3>
    {{end}}

  </body>
</html>
```

We store `Id` in a certain way and have a `.String()` method defined for displaying it.

When we use the package "text/template" the `Id` attribute displays correctly but when we use "html/template" it does not. My guess is that the former is calling `.String()` when displaying a variable and latter is not. I haven't been able to glean from the documentation what method is being called.

This is the first SO question I've ever written for Go. Hopefully made it clear but feel free to ask for additional info as I am a complete Go noob.

Thanks.

Comment: What *is* shown when using `html/template`?

Comment: Put a `fmt.Println("string")` inside your `String` method and you should see fast if is being called or not. Any chance your Id string has unsafe html string in it?

Comment: @EtienneBruines it prints out something like 123 456 789 and our `.String()` method would output 123-456-789. So, our `.String()` method basically adds dashes.

Comment: Explicitly calling `.String()` for the `html/template`, does that show the correct version? (doesn't answer your question, though) -- looking at [the code](https://golang.org/src/html/template/template.go?s=3012:3076#L90) for `template.Execute`, it seems to use the same function as the `text/template` part.

Comment: @EtienneBruines yes, we have tried explicitly calling `.String()` and it worked.

Comment: Since `html/template` should use `text/template` `Parse`, this is really weird. My first guess would be that there's a bug somewhere. What does this output? `fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(thatIdThingyYouWantToFormat))`? With dashes, or without? (perhaps they're using `fmt.Sprint`)

Comment: @EtienneBruines it prints without the dashes.

Comment: Then I would assume it uses `fmt.Sprint` or something similar, for the output. But looking at their code, I would disagree. Have you confirmed what @captncraig proposed?

Comment: @captncraig I did as you suggested and verified that the `.String()` method is not being called.

Comment: @EtienneBruines The `String()` method was defined with a pointer to the `Id` attribute. When changed it from using a pointer it now works as expected. I do not feel comfortable submitting it as an answer on Stackoverflow yet as this doesn't explain why @captncraig's suggestion didn't show the `String()` method was being called for both packages.